# Tracking push notifications in Android

Tags: android, android-notifications

Is it possible to track push notifications programmatically in android?

I mean to say is it possible to track the notifications appearing in the notification bar through some event, or service?

I have tried using AccessibilityService, but I haven't been able to track it using the TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATUS_CHANGED event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done using [NotificationListenerService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) from API 18.

A working example:

The service:

```
public class Test extends NotificationListenerService {


    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        super.onNotificationRemoved(sbn);

        //do your job
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        super.onNotificationPosted(sbn);

        //do your job
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<service android:name=".Test"
            android:label="Test"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

To get this work, you must enable the service which can be done through a settings link:

```
  Intent i=new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS");
                startActivity(i);
```

Comment: So onNotification posted() is the event to capture when a notification arrives on the status bar?

Comment: Yes, but don't forget to enable the service in settings as i said.

Comment: How to get the exact text of the notification?

Comment: As notifications can have custom layout, this can be tricky. What is a bigger problem to get the view,-according to my theory- you can get the notification's View by StatusBarNotification.getNotification() -> Notification.contentView, and then you can call apply() on the contentView to get the view, but it's just a theory...

Comment: OK will dabble and get back to you. Thanks @csenga